# How to pass request body data in type POST using Datatable for Serverside pagination using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I am trying to implement ServerSide pagination using Datatable for AJAX POST request

here is my Javascript Code, if I use JSON.stringify for data field then api won't hit

```
$('#tripboard_table').DataTable({
    proccessing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        "url": "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/trip/get-trip-list",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "json",
        "data": {
            "driver_id": "",
            "franchise_id": login_data.franchise_id,
            "page_no": 0,
            "page_size": 10
        }
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "" },
        { "data": "reference_number" },
        { "data": "consignor_name" },
        { "data": "consignee_name" },
        { "data": "from_city" },
        { "data": "to_city" },
        { "data": "status" },
        { "data": "route_name" },
        { "data": "vehicle_number" },
        { "data": "driver_name" },
        { "data": "pickup_date" },
        { "data": "scheduled_delivery_date" },
        { "data": "total_money_allocated" },
        { "data": "total_money_released" }
    ]



});
```

if we remove JSON.stringify function from data and passed data as it is then api gets hit and showing error alert that

> DataTables warning: table id=tripboard_table - Ajax error. For more
> information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

and no data is inserted in table.
In console it shows

> Method Not Allowed
> The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Please suggest solution for this..

Comment: _Method Not Allowed_: Your ajax URL endpoint (represented by `base_url + get_trip_list`) does not appear to be configured to accept `POST` requests. Maybe it is only configured for `GET` requests, currently.

Comment: What is the purpose of `page_no` and `page_size` in your request? If that is for DataTables pagination, then it is not needed, as DataTables already [automatically includes pagination data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) in its `serverSide` requests (see the `start` and `length` parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for adding to existing request of data table

```
function (d) {
                d.driver_id = "";
                d.franchise_id = login_data.franchise_id;
                d.page_no = 0;
                d.page_size = 10;
                return d;
            }
```

https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters

```
$('#tripboard_table').DataTable({
        proccessing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            "url": "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/trip/get-trip-list",
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.driver_id = "";
                d.franchise_id = login_data.franchise_id;
                d.page_no = 0;
                d.page_size = 10;
                return JSON.stringify(d)
                });
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "" },
            { "data": "reference_number" },
            { "data": "consignor_name" },
            { "data": "consignee_name" },
            { "data": "from_city" },
            { "data": "to_city" },
            { "data": "status" },
            { "data": "route_name" },
            { "data": "vehicle_number" },
            { "data": "driver_name" },
            { "data": "pickup_date" },
            { "data": "scheduled_delivery_date" },
            { "data": "total_money_allocated" },
            { "data": "total_money_released" }
        ]
    
    

    });
```

Comment: Please refer https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/template.html for custom column Template